# How to transform two NSDate objects into an ISO-8601 time interval duration?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, iso8601

Basically I want the opposite of this question:
[How to parse an ISO-8601 duration in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146416/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-duration-in-objective-c)
which asks for a transform from a [ISO-8601 time interval duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) to NSTimeInterval.

I want to go from two NSDate objects to a ISO-8601 time interval duration. Preferably I could specify the accuracy such as to the nearest year, month, or day etc. I was thinking I could strip the date components off each and create the duration that way but I was wondering if someone already made something that is battle tested and production ready.

Comment: What do you need to know?  You take the duration, apply modulo arithmetic to break it into the desired units, and format the result.

Comment: @HotLicks What is the ISO-8601 defined days per month? 28,29,30,31?

Comment: Close as I can tell, it's not defined.