# Represent ISO 8601 Durations in C++/Boost depending on current date

Tags: c++, boost, iso8601

ISO 8601 declares [duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) as `P[n]Y[n]M[n]DT[n]H[n]M[n]S`. For example, `P3Y0.5MT6M` means "3 years, half of the month and 3 minutes".

There are [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886140/parse-iso-8601-durations) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146416/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-duration-in-objective-c) to convert it to unixtime/chrono::duration/whatever, but all solutions I found uses average month and year duration in seconds, which is not correct according to the standard. Instead, it should depend on the date, for example `01 Feb + P1M` should be `01 Mar` (+28 days), while `01 Mar + P1M` should be `01 Apr` (+31 days).

Which way could I implement this? Do I have any better choise than manual implementation with all these leap-years and other nasty things handling?

Comment: Just a quick note. Fractional quantities are only allowed on the last unit specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to use the [date/time library that's being standardized for C++20](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0355r4.html). The [cleverly named Date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) can do the manipulations you suggest. It's `year_month_day` type can do month and year addition the way you want it to work.

Also, the conversion to a `time_point` is *correct*, to within the accuracy of the `time_point`'s integer type:

```
system_clock::time_point tp = sys_days{sun[5]/may/2016};
```

The `year_month_day` type is implemented in terms of the Gregorian calendar, which is incorporated into ISO 8601. This conversion therefore does not care about "averages" or anything. It gets the system-clock's epoch, and counts the actual number of days from that epoch to the given date. It will factor in all of the idiosyncrasies of the Gregorian calendar. Including leap years. Including those years that ought to be leap years but aren't. These will be counted correctly.

`tp` will therefore be the correct number of days, before the epoch or since, to the date in question.